# Error filtering template: Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php on line 304

Tags: magento2

> Error filtering template: Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be
>   empty in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php
>   on line 304

This issue is showing on live domain. In local and dev domain this issue is not coming.

Please help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is an image that is corrupted
you should find and remove it to have this fixed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in /etc/view.xml some sizes are missing, you can use the default file from luma theme and changes the image sizes in it and it should work.